# Es posible añadir texto a una imagen en Android Studio y despues tener la posibilidad de hacer zoom a la imagen más el texto?

Tags: android, kotlin, zoom

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual me muestra una imagen, esta imagen la utilizo a modo de plantilla, para que después de realizar varias operaciones matemáticas coloco los resultados dentro de varios textview y estos a su vez los coloco encima de la imagen, hasta aquí todo bién, el problema lo tengo que cuando hago zoom a la imagen para que el usuario pueda ver mejor los resultados solamente cambia de tamaño la imagen.

La pregunta es, hay algún método para hacer que el texto se pegue por completo a la imagen para que cuando se haga zoom cambien de tamaño los textview y la imagen a la vez ??

También se me ha ocurrido hacer la plantilla directamente con las herramientas del Android Studio y después poner los textview con los resultados de las operaciones, pero no sé si se podría hacer zoom al layout, sería posible ???ç

Un saludo.

Comment: El problema está, si es que entendí bien, que al momento de dar Zoom lo haces sobre la imagen por lo que está bien lo que sucede. Deberías, según lo que entendí por tu problema, hacer Zoom al objeto que compone todo el diseño. Es decir, por ejemplo, que este es tu diseño: -LinearLayout [ImageView-TextView-TextView]. A quién le debes hacer zoom, es al LinearLayout. Coméntame que tal te ha funcionado eso. Sino te funciona, te invito a compartirnos tu código para ver en qué se te puede ayudar.